# Query refactoring to avoid a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

The first table for notifications.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `my_notification` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `meta` json NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint GENERATED ALWAYS AS (coalesce(json_unquote(json_extract(`meta`,_utf8mb4'$.status')),0)) STORED,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

The second table has record related with first table *only* then customer read notification.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `my_client_notification` (
  `client_id` int NOT NULL,
  `notification_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
  KEY `notification_id` (`notification_id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `my_client` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`notification_id`) REFERENCES `my_notification` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

**How do I  get a list of the customer's notifications with the `is_read` flag without using a subquery?**

This is my current query:

```sql
SELECT
    JSON_SET(
        mn.meta,
        "$.id",
        mn.id,
        "$.is_read",
        (SELECT client_id FROM my_notification_client mnc
            WHERE mn.id=mnc.notification_id AND mnc.client_id = :client_id
        ) IS NOT NULL
    ) as meta,
FROM my_notification as mn
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT :offset, :limit
```

I can't use join because client_id condition removes some notification rows:

```
SELECT mn.id, msan.client_id FROM my_notification mn 
LEFT JOIN my_notification_client mnc ON (mn.id = mnc.notification_id)
WHERE client_id IS NULL OR client_id = 1
```

```
id|  client_id|
--+-----------+
 1|      86465|
 3|           |
```

Row with id 2 was missed.

Mysql 8.0.29

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: Start with a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for all relevant tables in phpMyAdmin or similiar or the mysql command line and copy/paste the output to your question

Comment: This should be asked in https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @LeandroBardelli It may be acceptable there but it is on-topic here; OP has a clear, objective criterion for answering: "*get a list of the customer's notifications with the is_read flag without using a subquery*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    JSON_SET(
        mn.meta,
        "$.id",
        mn.id,
        "$.is_read",
        COUNT(mnc.client_id) > 0
    ) as meta
FROM my_notification as mn
LEFT JOIN my_client_notification as mnc ON (mn.id = mnc.notification_id AND mnc.client_id = :client_id)
GROUP BY mn.id
ORDER BY mn.created_at DESC
LIMIT :offset, :limit;
```

This query will bring the two tables together by LEFT JOIN, and then apply a conditional aggregation (COUNT) to confirm the existence of a related record for the given client_id. If the count is greater than 0, the is_read flag will be set to true (1); otherwise, it will be false (0).

Comment: Thank you! Locanic and simple. How could I not remember about the grouping...